# How to get time difference between two times

Tags: ios, swift, time, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working on iOS swift application. And I am running timer for 6 minutes. In that 6 minutes user can do some task, Also I am showing cancel option too. User can cancel that task too after timer started.

In UI, I am showing timer decrement in label like 06:00, 05:59 till 00:00

So, I have to calculate how much time user has worked on that task.

So, total 6 minutes duration minus user worked time (like 10 seconds, 1 minute like that)

```
  let difference = testDuration(testTime: "00:10") //assume 10 seconds user taken test


func testDuration(testTime: String) -> String {
    let totalTestDuration = "06:00"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss"
    let totalTestTime = dateFormatter.date(from: totalTestDuration)!
    let userWalkedTime = dateFormatter.date(from: testTime)!

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let totalComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: totalTestTime)
    let userWalkedComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: userWalkedTime)

    let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: totalComponents, to: userWalkedComponents).minute!
    
    print("difference", difference)
    return String(difference)

}
```

> But, Always it is getting as 0

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have the `timeIntervalSince1970` cast both dates to that and compare? let startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let endTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(3600).timeIntervalSince1970
        let value: Double = endTime - startTime

Comment: do like if you want to perform 6 interval, initally add 6 minutes to your current time there after you want to check the remaing time = 6 min time - current time, you get the elapsed time

Comment: Using strings for your time intervals is the wrong approach.  You should use `TimeInterval` (which is in seconds) and simply convert to a string when you want to show the time to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this you need to get familiar with TimeIntervals.

The probably easiest approach would be to get the `timeIntervalSince1970`, which is representing the amount of seconds since **01.01.1970 00:00.**.

After that you can simply substract: `newDate.timeIntervalSince1970` - `oldDate.timeIntervalSince1970`

This gives you the seconds between these two dates. You can then convert the result into hours, days, etc.

```swift
let oldDate: Date = Your Old Date
let newDate: Date = Your New Date

let difference = newDate.timeIntervalSince1970 - oldDate.timeIntervalSince1970
```